# How to smooth out vertical concrete

Tags: concrete, basement, egress

I cut out a hole for an egress window but my foundation was hollow block. How would someone fill all this in and make a smooth surface for the window lumber? Can I build a form and kinda dump concrete in there? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: *For a rough opening?* You do nothing until it's done and then spray foam. ... I'm not sure what code says but I already don't like the schedule on those bolts in the header, and now presumably there's one above your head that does nothing.

Comment: @Tony Smith- you need to install support (lintel) under that block. It's usually a metal right angle piece that spans the opening and supported by block (or framing members) on each side.

Comment: @mazura Really? Foam isn’t exactly water resistant. I think I’d worry too much. That beam was designed by an engineer but yes I did lose two bolts when they cut the window. However, I have big 3.5” angle iron that goes on either side of the window that will probably do a lot for that beam. 

ojait I have 3.5” angle iron that is going on both sides and bottom. It’s my project this weekend.

Comment: Right, it's a window well; water infiltration. If you're going to go through the work of flattening it, I wouldn't put a rough opening. That would be 1000x better but a whole lot more work. - With the caisson already in place I'm not sure how you'd get membrane wrapped around. I think you're looking at caulking it. I don't have much more on "build a form and kinda dump concrete in there" other than, then skim coat. Or more than once, a little at a time, w/o a form, and stiff af.

Comment: @mazura I agree and started last night with some quick set polymer concrete....one layer at a time. Yeah, I didn’t think through it and no way I can get a wrap so I think you’re right. I’m just going to caulk the hell out of it. Or what about a layer of roofing tar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Barring some of the other issues, like what is holding the hollow block up over the window, and are the bolts through the double ledger going into the core of the hollow block or....I usually smooth out the rough spots with a grinder so all side are flat and reasonably plumb and level. It really needs to be flat. Then I set in place a pressure treated 2X8 cut to go across the bottom and one for the top. For the sides, I cut each side really snug so they need to be driven in with a beater block to help keep from splitting the wood and a hammer. Before hand, most pieces need to be dry fit to make sure they set well to the surfaces, since polyurethane construction adhesive will be smeared, shot, gunned, squeezed over the surfaces that will touch the wood before it is set in its final, permanent position.

Hold the PT material flush to the outside wall, since the inside can be filled with ripped material during the finishing stage. Before the window is set I would use a liquid applied waterproofing membrane to seal the outside from water infiltration. Then set the window, then seal that too. Then the outside can be trimmed out with PVC trim to finish it off, covering all the waterproofing that was applied....neatly.

Comment: The bolts are actually going into the void but with these cool anchors that you inject 2 part epoxy into and then it kinda foams out through screen as you insert the threaded rod. Kind cool. 

Great info! What do you mean by “liquid applied waterproofing membrane“?  I’m definitely concerned about water coming in and want to do everything I can to keep it out. Thanks!

Comment: Grace Bituthene Liquid Applied or Sika 2C SL are the materials I use to "paint" vertical wall surfaces. The Grace product is trowel grade and quite thick. The Sika product is much more fluid and will run off of a vertical surface if applied too heavily but will leave a thick film in the meantime. Perhaps with recesses left by the joint between the wood and block it would be best to use the Grace.

Comment: About the bolts and double ledger, did you check the spec about the system you used? Are the floor joists solely supported by the ledger? Did you have an engineer help you spec this detail out? If not, frame new walls under the ledgers or better yet, directly under the joists, to gain the support needed. The bolts do not seem close enough, nor staggered to do what is needed.